# Is my logic correct for trying to figure out Big-Oh arithmetic?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o

Hey I just wanted others to see if my answer to the problem that I was given to solve and explain but I wanted to double check to see if I did it correct.
We were given the task to find the sum of

```
Let T1 (N) = N^5 ,  T2(N) = e,  T3(N) = N^7/2   ,T4(N) = NclogN, T5(N) = N

T1 + T2 + T3 + T4 + T5
N + N^5 + e + N^7/2 + NcLogN + N
```

so first I know that out of `N + N^5 + N^7/2 = N^5`
then out of `e + Nclogn = e`
And now `e + N^5 = e since e grows exponentially quicker than N does`
Hopefully this all makes sense and afterwards I have to multiply them but I assume the result would be the same?

Comment: e is a constant, it doesn't grow.

Comment: So then N^5 would be better then?

Comment: `N^5` is the fastest growing function in your list

Comment: That's due to how fast it grows comparing to the rest right? and would it be the same if we multiplied them?

Answer (score 0):

`e` is a constant, and not an exponential function, and it represents this, mathematical constant, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_(mathematical_constant).

`N^5 + e = O(N^5)`

Btw,

`N^7/2 is different then N^(7/2)`

So,

`N + N^5 + e + N^7/2 + NcLogN + N = O(N^7/2)`

[You can check this graph](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20n%5E5%20,%20n%5E7%2F2,%20n*log(n),%20n,%20e%20for%20n%20from%200%20to%201000)

Comment: If that's the case, O((N^7)/2) == O(N^7)

Comment: It's N to the power of (7/2) which doesn't grow as fast as N^5

Comment: if its N power of (7/2) then yes it does not grow as fast as N^5. But, N^7/2 is  equivalent to (N^7)/2 which is O(N^7) . Check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations .